# Как сохранить отредактированные данные в datagrid wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Подскажите, как узнать какой элемент конкретно был отредактирован и сохранить его ?

Comment: Привязку используете? Приведите модель, к которой привязываетесь

Comment: Можно использовать в привязке `SelectedItem` например.

Comment: Нет , можно привязать datagrid к list ?

Comment: Можно и к List, вы к чему привязываете?

Comment: я не знаю как привязать его к list , искала databinding но безуспешно
Мне нужно чтобы отредактированная информация в datagrid сохранялась в моем list

Comment: `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"/>`

Comment: это надо прописать к xaml ? и не подскажете как  это связать с MEssagebox  т.е если пользртель внес какие-то изменения как показать ему MessageBox (" вы хотите сохранить изменения ? " ) и сохранить только при нажатии на да

Comment: Покажите модель данных, которую вы отображаете в `DataGrid` и расскажите о месте хранения данных подробнее

Comment: В датагрид у меня отображается информация которая хранится в листе. Лист в свою очередь показывает информацию , которая содержится в файле типа .dat 
В чем в принципе заключается мой вопрос : 
Как сделать так, чтобы информацию отредактированную пользователем в датагрид сохранять с своем листе